# Laravel Eloquent for hasMany relation cannot find records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I can not find why it does not work.

In my Course model I have defined relation:

```
class Course extends Model {

    public function courseDates() {
        return $this->hasMany(CourseDate::class, 'course_id');
    }

}
```

And in my CourseDate model this:

```
class CourseDate extends Model {

    public function course() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }

}
```

When I try to access CourseDates from Course I will always get null, but when I access Course from CourseDate, it works and I see all data:

```
var_dump(CourseDate::where('id', 1)->first()->course->name); => output: "Course 1"
var_dump(Course::where('id', 1)->first()->courseDate); => output: null
```

And what's strange when I try it with another course (like ID 2) then it works. The data is absolutely the same in the database. Any Ideas?

Comment: Check class name in `CourseDate` model. Please add your database details.

Comment: You have a typo in your `var_dump`. You are trying to access `courseDate` but the relationship method is called `courseDates`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldent add class like `CourseDate::class` instead you should add it like below

```
class Course extends Model {
   public function courseDates() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\CourseDate', 'course_id');
   }
}
```

And in your `CourseDate` model

```
class CourseDate extends Model {
   public function course() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
   }
}
```

And your relationship method for `Course` model is `courseDates` so you should use it like below

```
var_dump(Course::where('id', 1)->first()->courseDates);
```

Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships